# Execute parallel create/merge using only Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher script which loads the content from a CSV and then tries to load it into the graph. What it basically looks like is something similar to that:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///data.csv'
AS row
MERGE (o:Order {Id:toInteger(row.tr_ID)})
    ON CREATE SET 
        o.Created = toInteger(row.tr_Created)
        
// read credit card and create a relation to an order (if applicable)
FOREACH (n IN CASE WHEN row.cc_CrdId = 'NULL' THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
    MERGE (cc:CreditCard {Id:row.cc_CrdId})
        ON CREATE SET
            cc.Created = toInteger(row.cc_CrdCreated)
    MERGE (o)-[:WITH_CC]->(cc)
)
```

This script reads the file row by row. But I was wondering if it is somehow possible to execute the logic for multiple rows in parallel.

I saw [this](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/parallel/) article for parallel cypher but don't really understand how I could use it. I don't know if some kind of **lock** needs to be implemented.